# How can I catch a EOF error in my calculator program

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, calculator, eoferror

I am trying to create a calculator. Why can't I catch the EOF error? My program crashes when I input more than one special characters. e.g. 2++

How is this problem normally solved?

Thanks in advance!

```
def calcfieldcheck(input):
    return re.match("^[0-9\.\-\/\*\+\%]+$",input)
    #uitzoeken hoe regex nesten


def calculate(input):

    print "Wat moet ik berekenen?"

    counter=0


    while not calcfieldcheck(input):
        if counter > 0:
            print "Je kan alleen getallen en expressies berekenen!"
            input=raw_input("> ")
        else:
            print
            input=raw_input("> ")

        counter=counter+1
        print
        print "je hebt het volgende ingevoerd: ",input

    try:
        print "het resultaat is:", eval(input)
    except EOFError:
        print "EOFError, je calculatie klopt niet."
        input=raw_input("> ")
    print
    print       

    counter=0
```

Comment: What makes you think `EOFError` is the rigth exception to catch for evaluation errors?

Comment: Are you sure you know what an `EOFError` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `eval()`, which will try to interpret the expression as a Python expression. Python expressions can raise *any number* of exceptions, but `EOFError` is one of the least likely.

Catch `Exception` instead:

```
try:
    print "het resultaat is:", eval(input)
except Exception:
    print "Oeps, je calculatie klopt niet."
```

which is the base class for all 'regular' exceptions.

You can assign the exception to a local name and print out the message with your error message:

```
try:
    print "het resultaat is:", eval(input)
except Exception as err:
    print "Oeps, je calculatie klopt niet:", err
```

The better approach would be to parse the expression and perhaps use the functions of the [`operator` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) to make the calculations.

The [`EOFError` exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError) is raised by the `raw_input()` function when input is closed without any data being received:

```
>>> raw_input('Close this prompt with CTRL-D ')
Close this prompt with CTRL-D Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError
```

Unless you pass a string containing a `raw_input()` or `input()` call to the `eval()` function you will not encounter that exception.

Comment: Thanks for your help Martijn. I will look into the whole parsing thing. I had a feeling that this wasn't the correct way to solve it.